# turning jquery mobile and php mysql into apk file

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, jquery-mobile, phonegap

I made an app using **jquery mobile**, **php** and **mysql** and now  I'm trying to convert into `.apk` file using **phonegap** for desktop.

But I have a problem with my php code because it doesn't work, phonegap doesn't recognize php code.

Is there a way can do it to convert both jquery mobile code and php & mysql into .apk?

I will post the whole code if it's necessarily or another way to do this, please help!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately not.
You would have to separate your server-side and client-side code.

HTML & jQuery Mobile would be your client, which you could turn into your app.
PHP & mySQL would be your server, which you could not put in your app.

You would then communicate between the client and the server by calling [Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) in client code, you might also like to use a framework like [CakePHP](https://cakephp.org/) on the server.

Good luck!!